# Robot Framework use an yaml file as an argument in a keyword

Tags: robotframework

I would like to know if it is possible to call a keyword with a yaml file as an argument.

Let me describe my concern.

Actually my project structure is the following:

- one test suite (main.robot),
- one resource file (myResource.robot)
- and one variable file (parameter.yaml)

  ---

**main.robot**

```
*** Settings **
Resource | myResource.robot

*** Test Cases **
Test1
| keyword1
```

**myResource.robot**

```
** Settings ***
Variables | parameter.yaml

** Keywords ***
keyword1
| blablabla
```

---

From my test suite, I would like to call several times the same keyword (named keyword1 in my example) but with different parameters (defined in yaml file). As the yaml is defined in the resource file, I need to duplicate many times the resource file with different yaml files. But this is not efficient.

My idea is to define several yaml files, and call the keyword from the test suite. Each call would be done with a different yaml file
Is it possible to call my keyword with the yaml file as an argument? If yes,  how to handle the variables in the resource file.

Comment: Are you asking how to read and process the yaml file in the keyword? The literal answer to the question of whether you can pass a yaml file is "yes", but I think you're asking more than just how to pass the name of the file.

Comment: With the information you provided you're trying to implement a solution that may not be the right one for your problem. Resource Files are static and there are several ways to call them several times with different input resulting in a different output. This does not require multiple YAML files. So, please provide us a bit more background info on what is in the YAML file and what you're trying to achieve in functional terms.